# Swift TableView Cell Unable to Display the data from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I created four label inside the table view cell to fetch the data from Api . The link is https://coinmap.org/api/v1/venues/ . I have two swift file one is to define the tabelview property and other one is for Label with cell . When I run the app it displaying the tableview cell but not displaying the data with label . Here is the model .

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Coin: Codable {
    let venues: [Venue]
}

// MARK: - Venue
struct Venue: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let lat, lon: Double
    let category, name: String
    let createdOn: Int
    let geolocationDegrees: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, lat, lon, category, name
        case createdOn = "created_on"
        case geolocationDegrees = "geolocation_degrees"
    }
}
```

Here is the Network Manager .

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    func getCoins(from url: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Coin, NetworkError>) -> Void ) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            completion(.failure(.badURL))
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(.other(error)))
                return
            }

            if let data = data {
                //decode
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coin.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(response))
                } catch let error {
                    completion(.failure(.other(error)))
                }
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is the presenter .

```
class VenuePresenter : VanueProtocol{

    // creating instance of the class
    private let view : VanueViewProtocol
    private let networkManager: NetworkManager
    private var vanues = [Venue]()
    var rows: Int{
        return vanues.count
    }
    // initilanize the class
    init(view:VanueViewProtocol , networkmanager:NetworkManager = NetworkManager()){
        self.view = view
        self.networkManager = networkmanager
    }
    
    
    func getVanue(){
        
        let url  = "https://coinmap.org/api/v1/venues/"
        
        networkManager.getCoins(from: url) { result in
            
            switch result {
            case.success(let respone):
                self.vanues = respone.venues
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               self.view.resfreshTableView()
                           }
                       case .failure(let error):
                           DispatchQueue.main.async {
                               self.view.displayError(error.errorDescription ?? "")
                               print(error)
                           }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    

    func getId(by row: Int) -> Int {
        return vanues[row].id
    }
    
    func getLat(by row: Int) -> Double {
        return vanues[row].lat
    }
    
    func getCreated(by row: Int) -> Int {
        return vanues[row].createdOn
    }
    
    func getLon(by row: Int) -> Double? {
        return vanues[row].lon
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is the view controller .

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    
    private var presenter : VenuePresenter!
   
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpUI()
        presenter = VenuePresenter(view: self)
        presenter.getVanue()
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DisplayView1")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    private func setUpUI() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    
}

extension ViewController : VanueViewProtocol{
    func resfreshTableView() {
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
       func displayError(_ message: String) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let doneButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(doneButton)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        presenter.rows
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DisplayView.identifier, for: indexPath) as? DisplayView
          else { return UITableViewCell() }
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        let id   = presenter.getId(by: row)
         let lat = presenter.getLat(by: row)
        guard let lon = presenter.getLon(by: row) else { return UITableViewCell() }
        let createdOn = presenter.getCreated(by: row)
        cell.configureCell(id: id, lat: lat, lon: lon, createdOn: createdOn)
        return cell
    }
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Here is the display view swift .

```
class DisplayView: UITableViewCell{
    
    static let identifier = "DisplayView1"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    
    func configureCell(id: Int ,lat : Double , lon : Double , createdOn: Int){
        label1.text = String(id)
        label2.text = String(lat)
        label3.text = String(lon)
        label4.text = String(createdOn)
    
    }
   
    
    
}
```

Here is the screenshot is empty not displaying the data .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering a generic cell:

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DisplayView1")
```

You need to register your custom cell:

```
self.tableView.register(DisplayView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: DisplayView.identifier)
```